# Converting MYSQL queries to HQL

Tags: mysql, hql

We just migrated from MYSQL to Oracle 11g and I have to change some queries since I had coded the for MYSQL specifically. So we are planning to use HQL for our queries. Is there any particular approach to doing this conversion? Like many places I have used 'Limit' and other MYSQL specific keywords.. (we are using grails/groovy for development, so its a domain classes based model). Is there any specific tool which can do the conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any particular tool that would automatically do this for you. However, HQL can easily accommodate your mySQL queries.

I think for complex queries, best option would be to use **[`executeQuery`](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html)** - basically HQL queries.

To make queries more readable, use **[`createCriteria`](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)**.

I tend to use both in my grails applications. However, whenever possible I use `createCriteria` to make it more readable.